# Как передать переменную в контроллер? (AJAX+PHP+MVC)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mvc, controller

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь передать POST переменную в контроллер на PHP через AJAX:

```
   $(".inp_pr").keypress(function(f) {
   if (f.which == 13) {
   dataString = 'qwe';
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/prwrk/",
   data: 'dataString=' + dataString,
   success: function(data) {
   alert('<?php echo($data)?>');
   }
   });
   event.preventDefault();
   }
   });
```

Код контроллера:

```
   function action_index()
   {
    $data=$_POST['dataString'];
    $this->view->generate('prwrk_view.php', 'template_view.php',$data);
   }
```

AJAX успешно отправляет переменную, но в контроллер PHP она не приходит. Есть подозрения, что я не правильно указываю Url, но, даже прописывая прямой путь до нужного контроллера переменная не передается.

Код роутера:

```
<?php
class Route
{
static function start()
{

    $controller_name = 'Main';
    $action_name = 'index';

    $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if ( !empty($routes[1]) )
    {   
        $controller_name = $routes[1];
    }




    if ( !empty($routes[2]) )
    {
        $action_name = $routes[2];
    }



    $model_name = 'Model_'.$controller_name;
    $controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller_name;
    $action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;



    $model_file = strtolower($model_name).'.php';
    $model_path = "application/models/".$model_file;
    if(file_exists($model_path))
    {
        include "application/models/".$model_file;
    }


    $controller_file = strtolower($controller_name).'.php';
    $controller_path = "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
    if(file_exists($controller_path))
    {
        include "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
    }
    else
    {

        Route::ErrorPage404();
    }


    $controller = new $controller_name;
    $action = $action_name;

    if(method_exists($controller, $action))
    {

        $controller->$action();
    }
    else
    {

        Route::ErrorPage404();
    }

}

function ErrorPage404()
{
    $host = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    header('Location:'.$host.'404');
}
}
?>
```

Как правильно отправить переменную в PHP-контроллер из AJAX?

Comment: информации побольше можете добавить? если переходить по вашему урлу '/prwrk/', мы в action_index попадем? в firebug при отправке ajax ошибка есть какая-нибудь? или просто все проходит, но в action_index $_POST пустой? что alert ваш в success возвращает?

Comment: Да, если перейти по урлу '/prwrk/', мы попадаем сразу в action_index. Никаких ошибок в отладчике нет, пишет что пост запрос успешно отправлен.  Алерт в success возвращает пустое значение. Вставил в action_index код `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  $data='получено';
  }
  else{
  $data='нет';
  }` , теперь всегда получаю в алерте success'а "Нет"

Comment: кстати, не обратил внимания. странный у вас alert - alert('<?php echo($data)?>'); он же отобразит вам значение переменной $data в тот момент, когда вы просто перешли на страницу, без ajax. чтобы получить результат ajax запроса (т.е. то, что возвращает action_index), вам нужно использовать alert(data)

Comment: alert(data) возвращает мне html-код текущей страницы...

Comment: сделайте вот что. замените ваш action_index на function action_index() { print_r($_POST);}, ваш алерт замените на alert(data) и гляньте, что выведет

Comment: если вы конечно не с него же отправляете ajax :) ну или добавьте print_r($_POST); в самое начало вашего action_index; в html, который отобразится в alert, найдите место, где $_POST распечатался, и проверьте, что там лежит

Comment: Спасибо за совет, теперь есть хоть какой-то прогресс :)) Добавил в контроллер строку `$data= print_r($_POST); `, теперь в алерт выводится Array ([dataString] => qwe) и стена кода html

Comment: мне кажется, вы немножко запутались. смотрите, когда вы просто заходите на страницу (я так понимаю, на ту же action_index), у вас $_POST изначально пустой. значит и $data пустой. потом вы $data передаете во вьюху, так? во вьюхе у вас alert('<?php echo($data)?>');. т.е. в исходном коде страницы по сути на success будет навешано function(data) {   alert('');   }. ну и алерт всегда будет пустой. т.е. пост переменная по ajax запросу-то передается, но что с ней дальше делать, и что вы хотите получить в результате ajax запроса, надо подумать

Comment: Да, вы правы. Изначально пользователь попадает на страницу, где выполняется action_index. $_post изначально пустой. Изначально закладывалась такая мысль: пользователь что-то вводит в инпут, нажимает enter, после чего выполняется ajax, который передает переменную в action_index контроллера. Оттуда эта переменная попадает в модель, где подставляется в параметр запроса. После выполнения запроса, модель возвращает в контроллер результат. Контроллер, в свою очередь, отдает этот результат во вьюху.